# Aliasing object's property name + defining it's type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to **(1)** alias a returning object's property name + **(2)** defining it's type.

So far it was easy to alias the property name, but I can't find a way to define it's type.

**NOTE:** I know I can cast it in my function body like this `(<Car>car).id`, but I want to know if I can define it in the parameters declaration.

**NOTE:** `dropModel` is not my function, it's an imported package's function.

---

Here is a simple [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nbs-angular-alias-type-definition) with my problem. look at `app.component.ts` file for line 33 and see that my item is `any`. How do I defines it as `Vemp` class?

---

**My code:**

```
this.myService.dropModel('cars').subscribe(({ target: team, item: car }) => {
  const targetTeamId = team.id;
  const droppedCarId = car.id;
})
```

As you can see, I've aliased `target` property to be `team` and `item` to `car`, now I can use them in my code and it's much better to understand it.

The problem that this code is not type safe, `team` and `car` are `any`.

---

**dropModel Function declaration:**

```
dropModel: (groupName?: string) => Observable<{
  target: any;
  item: any;
}>;
```

Comment: If `target` and `item` properties are both of type `any`, then it's not surprising that assigning them to new variables will preserve the `any` type.  Looks like `dropModel` should be typed differently, but without a [mcve] it's hard to say to what it should be changed.  I suppose you can do `({target: team, item: car}:{target: Team, item: Car}) => ...`?  I'd like a self-contained reproducible example to be sure, though.

Comment: Why are you not giving target and item a type in the function declaration?

Comment: @dezfowler `dropModel` is not my function

Comment: @jcalz updated my question with an stackBlitz demo

Comment: You could just override the type definition. Redefine dropModel something like this...  `dropModel(groupName: 'cars'): Observable<{target: Team, item: Car}>`. See the interface IDocument example here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: I guess I can do that, but my question is more global. I mean that this is just a specific case, what with other cases? Each time I'll need to re-define the source function? It's not making any sense...

Comment: @benshabatnoam For that example I'd probably just call it like `this.dragulaService.dropModel<Vemp>("VAMPIRES")...` since `dropModel` is generic in the type of `item`.  It's not much safer than a type assertion, but it does avoid using `any`.  I'll turn this into an answer if you edit the code in the question to be an actual [mcve]; externally linked code is a nice extra but can't be relied on since it can change.  Please consult the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.  Good luck!

Comment: Hello @jcalz, I know I can do that in the demo but it is not my question. That's why in my question I didn't reviled that `dropModel` is generic. This is just a quick demo I found demonstrating my question. I guess it's not the best one. My question is what if `dropModel` is not generic, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the type of your aliased object, like:

```js
dropModel('cars').subscribe(({
  target: team,
  item: car
}: { 
  target: Team,
  item: Car
}) => {
  const targetTeamId = team.id;
  const droppedCarId = car.id;
});
```

But, it would be more convenient to declare the result type:

```js
interface TargetItem<TTarget, TItem> {
  target: TTarget,
  item: TItem
}

const dropModel: (groupName?: string) => Observable<TargetItem<any, any>> = ...

dropModel('cars').subscribe(({ target: team, item: car }: TargetItem<Team, Car>) => {
  const targetTeamId = team.id;
  const droppedCarId = car.id;
});
```

Or use generic function instead:

```js
const dropModel: <TTarget, TItem>(groupName?: string) => Observable<{
  target: TTarget;
  item: TItem;
}> = ...;

dropModel<Team, Car>('cars').subscribe(({target: team, item: car}) => {
  const targetTeamId = team.id;
  const droppedCarId = car.id;
})
```